# Does the debug.log do log rotation?

Tags: php, debug, apache, logging

This is more like of an inquiry.
So I enabled my WP_DEBUG_LOG to true.
It does work though, debug.log is in my wp-content's directory.
But does it also do log rotation like different file for each day?
Example:
Today's file - debug.log
Yesterday's  - 2019-12-18-101010-debug.log

Does it work like this? Or just debug.log all through out?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, it creates only one file. There is no log rotation involved.

But... Sometimes “but” can be a good thing ;)

WP uses error_log for its debug log, so you can change its location using:

```
ini_set( 'error_log', WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/debug-' . date('Y-m-d') . '.log' );
```

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you!!!!!!!

Comment: Thank you, but where do you configure this ? ini_set( 'error_log', WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/debug-' . date('Y-m-d') . '.log' );

Comment: @Hari Generally, if you have access you would want to set this in your servers `php.ini` file. If you don't have access to edit this file you can try putting it into the root `wp-config.php`.